# Decidability of Mixed-Integer Semidefinite Programs

Tags: decidability, semidefinite-programming, undecidability

Semidefinite programs (SDP) have an "efficient" solution, as a convex problem, by e.g. the ellipsoid method; but this comes with standard caveats as the output can be exponentially long (there is a problem of size $O(n)$ that requires integers that are $O(2^n)$ bits). All the same, it admits an exponential-time algorithm to some precision, and Tarski's generic algorithm for satisfiability over the reals means that it can be decided exactly.

Integer Linear Programs are NP-hard, but admit a very straightforward exponential-time search if all the variables have bounds; when they don't have bounds, there are [still exponential time algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_programming#Exact_algorithms_for_a_small_number_of_variables).

A natural question is: what happens when these are combined? I can find essentially no theoretical results on the question.

When quadratic constraints are present (MIQP), if the quadratic terms are non-convex, the problem is undecidable (because you can create arbitrary polynomials). I can't find any information on what happens they are convex.

There's some literature on *practical* software implementations to solve *bounded* MISDPs, see [this](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Eboyd/papers/pdf/int_least_squares.pdf) and [this](https://wwwopt.mathematik.tu-darmstadt.de/preprints/ulbrich/Sulb2017_6.pdf) and [this](https://co-at-work.zib.de/slides/Donnerstag_17.9/MISDP.pdf). [This](https://www.lix.polytechnique.fr/%7Eliberti/rairo18.pdf) discussed some undecidability of stuff of general non-convex MINLPs, but made no statement about MISDPs or convex MIQP.

So, two questions I guess:

- Is MISDP decidable? Is there, say, a singly-exponential algorithm for it?
- And likewise for convex MIQP.